# Create my Silverlight Form designer

Tags: silverlight

I need to create my own form designer in Silverlight.
Are there some free/ not free designers or other things which I can use in the start?
Thanks

Comment: There's a decent designer available out-of-the-box in the free Visual Studio Web Developer Express 2010 and a *great* designer available in paid Expression Blend 4.  What do you need that's not available in either of those tools?

Answer (score 0):

Blend 4 is the defacto designer tool for XAML based applications. Though with Visual Studio 2010 some design is allowed via drag and drop. Though doing it through Blend 4 will make it much easier to design something complex.